# Apache POI formatting double numbers in Excel files

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using apache-poi for creating some reports. I have an issue with the decimal separator. Right now I have the following displayed in the excel file:

For 111.2343 -> 111.23

For 111.23   -> 111.23

For 111.2    -> 111.2

**For 111      -> 111.** (see the dot at the end)

The problem is with 111 number. I don't want to see the trailing dot (or comma, depending on language).

Here is my current code to format the cells. Can this be achieved using apache-poi?

Thank you,

Iulian

PS: Is there a way to use java.text.Format in poi? I see this has [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown method which does what I want.

```
private void createColumnStyle(XSSFSheet sheet, int maxRows,int col)
{
    XSSFWorkbook wb = sheet.getWorkbook();

    XSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
    font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)10);
    font.setFontName("Calibri");

    XSSFCellStyle colStyle = wb.createCellStyle();  
    colStyle.setFont(font);                
    colStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);

    colStyle.setBorderBottom(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    colStyle.setBorderTop(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    colStyle.setBorderRight(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    colStyle.setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);

    CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();                   
    colStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("#,##0.##"));


    for (int i=3; i<maxRows; i++ )
    {
        XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(i).createCell(col);
        cell.setCellStyle(colStyle);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you set up Excel to format the cell how you want it to be displayed, and read that back in Apache POI, what format string does excel save to get that?

Comment: @Gagravarr And that format would be... :) ?

Comment: I've no idea, but that's an entirely different problem! Once you know what to format it as in Excel, write the file out, read it in with POI, see what the format really is (Excel sometimes translates the format strings on write), and finally have POI write the cell style in that format

Answer (score 0):

Using `DecimalFormat` works fine for all the cases:

```
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
double cellValue = Double.valueOf(dec.format(111));
XSSFCell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(cellValue);
```

this set the cell value to `111` only.

Comment: I want to set the **cell style** for the entire column. The cell values are numbers so I'm interested in a cell style that is interpreted by excel according to my requirements (see the question).